# Firebase cloud messaging not received by some devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I faced a problem took my time for 5 days.
When I send push notifications with FCM, web service response back success as below

```
{"multicast_id":7792208922657857316,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1501588248469528%fdb01da9f9fd7ecd"}]}[]
```

But it not received in some devices.
just for inform you it can received by some other devices.
I searched several sites but my problem is remained yet.

Answer (score 2):

The multicast_id is just a confirmation that your request has been accepted by the FCM server. 
Possible issues why push was not received on some devices:

1. Device offline in the given ttl
2. App was force stopped by the user/battery saving app/launcher customisations like MIUI, OPPO color OS etc
3. User un-installed the app. Google at times is not able to able to mark the user uninstalled immediately.

Comment: Thank you.
But no one of your mentioned options are not happend to me, i checked all. I send message to other device in same time, it receive but this one not receive.
Just for inform you i has similar app that it sen push notification, when i use it this device can receive successfully.
I totally confused